# setting a default value for an ICollection<string> DTO's property in c#

Tags: c#, properties, default-value, icollection

If I have an ICollection property and I need to set a default string value.

```
public class UserDTO : LoginUserDTO
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public ICollection<string> Roles { get; set; } = new List<string>() { "User" };
}
```

I need the default role to be a user every time I use this DTO in the controller, however, it is always empty as you can see in the swagger image below

[image]

How do I set the default Role to User??

Answer (score 3):

Here is the correct syntax.

```
public ICollection<string> Roles { get; set; } = new List<string>() { "User" };
```

Your example cannot work since you try to add a value inside a collection that is not instantiated. (At that time "Role" is null).

Second issue. Since "Add" return "void", it cannot be assigned to the collection itself.

This example will only work in C# 6 or above. If you are not using it you have to do it "the old way" in the constructor:

```
public UserDTO() 
{
    Roles = new List<string>() { "User" };
}
```